# Updating User Credentials in Yodlee

Tags: yodlee

With the Yodlee API, a new user is registered in the system with a login and password using the [register3](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_SOAP_API_Reference/register3) API, my question is, is it possible to change these credentials at a later date via an API? I can't seem to find an answer on how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this via an API. Please mail developer@yodlee.com with the request or connect with Yodlee Consultant over live chat present on developer.yodlee.com. You'll get the required information. This information is going to be available over the developer.yodlee.com soon.